# checkboxes on word document via vba -> run time error '5941'

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-word

I have an excel chart and based on the answers in a distinct column (full range,use range, single point comparison) a cross at the corresponding checkbox belonging to one of the mentioned options should be done. Basically it is rather an easy task, but I always get the run time error 5941: The requested member of the collection does not exist. And I do not know why exactly, bcs the checkboxes in the corresponding word document each do have the exact same name as in the vba-code. Am I doing sth fundamentally wrong here?
The error occurs in the row of doctest.FormFields("Checkox1")...

```
Dim appWd As New Word.Application
Dim wbXL As New Excel.Application
Dim userInput As String
    userInput = InputBox("Enter the number of WX-Form:", "WX-Form Number")

'for the loop

Dim newInput As String
Dim newRange As String
Dim searchcolumn As Range
Dim Cal_Bereich As String
Dim Lieferanten_Cal_Zertifikate As String

AmountWX = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A3:A2000"), userInput)

'every row is a formular

For b = 1 To AmountWX
    newInput = userInput & " Nr." & b
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'first row with userinput should be found
    Set searchcolumn = Range("A:A")
    For Each cell In searchcolumn
        If cell.Value = userInput Then
            ' when input was found the loop should finish
            firstrow = cell.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Zelle
    newRange = "B" & firstrow + b - 1
    Range(newRange) = newInput
      
    Set appWd = New Word.Application
    appWd.Visible = True
    Set doctest = appWd.Documents.Add("C:\Users\formular.docx")
    doctest.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'some bookmark assignements

Cal_Bereich = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(newRange), Range("B3:N2000"), 13, False)
    Select Case Cal_Bereich
        Case "Full range"
            doctest.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True
        Case "Use range"
            doctest.FormFields("Checkbox2").CheckBox.Value = True
        Case "Single point comparison"
            doctest.FormFields("Checkbox3").CheckBox.Value = True
    End Select
    Set Anmeldeformular = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing
        
Next b

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you simply set a breakpoint when you want to set the checkboxes and check the `FormFields`-Collection of the word document. Use the Locals or Watch window for that.

Comment: The obvious question: are the controls you inserted in the Word document definitely legacy FormField checkboxes and not ContentControl checkboxes or ActiveX checkboxes? They each need different code to set their values.